# How to set a header in an HTTP response?

Tags: java, http, servlets, http-headers

I've a servlet *A* where I'm setting a header in the HTTP response:

```
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

    String userName=request.getParameter("userName");
    String newUrl = "http://somehost:port/ServletB";

    response.addHeader("REMOTE_USER", userName);

    response.sendRedirect(newUrl);
}
```

Now in a servlet *B*, I'm trying to get the header value that was set in the servlet *A*:

```
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

    String userid = request.getHeader("REMOTE_USER");
}
```

But here the value of *userid* is coming as `null`. Please let me know what I'm missing here.

Comment: @Nambari, Could you please let me know if I want to send userid info to ServletB then how would I set this using existing header?

Comment: because another application that I want to send userinfo, it accepts header or cookie for SSO implementation.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

First of all you have to understand the nature of

```
response.sendRedirect(newUrl);
```

It is giving the client (browser) 302 http code response with an URL.
The browser then makes a separate GET request on that URL.
And that request has no knowledge of headers in the first one.

So sendRedirect won't work if you need to pass a header from Servlet A to Servlet B.

If you want this code to work - use RequestDispatcher in Servlet A (instead of sendRedirect). Also, it is always better to use relative path.

```
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
throws ServletException, IOException
{
    String userName=request.getParameter("userName");
    String newUrl = "ServletB";
    response.addHeader("REMOTE_USER", userName);
    RequestDispatcher view = request.getRequestDispatcher(newUrl);
    view.forward(request, response);
}
```

========================

```
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
{
    String sss = response.getHeader("REMOTE_USER");
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In my Controller, I merely added an HttpServletResponse parameter and manually added the headers, no filter or intercept required and it works fine:

```
httpServletResponse.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
httpServletResponse.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, OPTIONS");
httpServletResponse.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers","Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, X-Auth-Token, X-Csrf-Token, WWW-Authenticate, Authorization");
httpServletResponse.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "false");
httpServletResponse.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
```

Answer (score 0):

Header fields are not copied to subsequent requests. You should use either cookie for this (addCookie method) or store "REMOTE_USER" in session (which you can obtain with getSession method).